# Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, be $f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{2n+2}3\right\rfloor$

Tags: functions

> Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, be $f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{2n+2}3\right\rfloor$. Is f one-to-one? Is f onto?

I found it quite easy to find a counter-example for $f$ not being one-to-one. $f(2)=f(3)$, but $2\neq 3$.

It is evident through mapping that $f$ is onto, but how do I prove it formally? I can't find the inverse because $x=(3y-2)/2$ is not always a natural number.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** For an integer $m$ we have

$$\left\lfloor\frac{2n+2}3\right\rfloor =m \Leftrightarrow m \leq \frac{2n+2}3 < m+1 $$

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that:
$$f(3k)=f(3k-1)=2k,f(3k+1)=2k+1 $$

hence the function is onto

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use induction.   The base case is obvious, $f(1)=1$.   Now assume that a number $n$ is in the range, so it has a preimage,  $f(k)=n$.  Examine the possible values of $f(k+1)$,  you can easily show (Ask if you get stuck)), that the possible values are $n$ and $n+1$.  If $n+1$, you are done,  otherwise show that $f(k+2)=n+1$ and you are done.